# to handle multi line records in hive

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hiveql

I have data something like this in CSV file:

```
1|abc|"Hello,
how are you"|pqr
2|xyz|I am fine|tuv
3|hjd|what abt you|klf
```

You can see we have a multiline record in CSV.Although I can load this in hive table. But it will not show me the correct result.
How can I handle multiline records to load in hive

Comment: use field delimiter as | (pipe)

Comment: That wont help mate.I have tried this . Issue is with multi line record

Comment: Have you considered using Spark?

Comment: Kindly check my answer and upvote/accept, if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive is suitable for structured dataset, where the column sequence and delimiters are well defined. In your case, the EOL character is row delimiter and can occur in the dataset as well. Due to this, the data is semi structured.

You have few options:

1. If the file is being generated by any other program, you should
   change the row delimiter to something else than a newline. The best
   practice is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for column delimiter and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for row delimiter.
2. If option 1 is not feasible, Write a map-reduce with custom record reader implementation, where record reader could determine the boundary of one record (i.e. logic to pick one complete record). Reformat the record in the map reduce program to output records delimited with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (columns delimiter) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (row delimiter). Now, you may load the file in hive.